# Clarification on MIPS sw and lw

Tags: mips

If I have the following code in C

```
A[1] = 2;
```

Where the starting address A[0] is $s0.

```
addi $t0, $s0, 1 #t0->A[0]
lw $t1, 0($t0) #t1->A[1]
addi $t1, $t1, 2
```

This is where I am a bit confused. Is it necessary to add:

```
sw $t1, 0($t1)
```

Or is the code fine as is? I think it is fine because, I am adding 2 to the contents of $t1, which is effectively, A[1] = 2.

Comment: Isn't this more of a question for Stackoverflow?

Comment: In the C code, you are storing one literal into an array.  In the assembly code you're adding a literal into a variable whose value is loaded from the array.  Without the store instruction, this becomes `x = A[1] + 2;`, and with the store instruction this becomes `A[1] += 2;`.  Neither of which is the C code you've posted.

Comment: The comments in the assembly code seem quite confusing, are you sure they say what you intended them to say?

Comment: I also think there is a typo in the store instruction, you're storing to `0($t1)` instead of `0($t0)`

Comment: You must have been quite confused by something.  Why did you load the value of A[1] into a register?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If &A is stored in $s0, then `A[1] = 2` compiles to

```
ori $t0, $0, 2      # Move 2 into $t0
sw $t0, 4($s0)      # Store $t0 into $s0 + 4 (because ints are 4 bytes)
```

As mentioned in the comments, your code doesn't make a lot of sense because you seem to be doing something resembling `x = A[1] +2`. You have to use a `sw` because the C code stores a value to the array.